# server side redering with react-router 4 is not working

Tags: reactjs, express, serverside-javascript, react-router-v4

I am trying to do server side rendering with react-router 4, but I am receiving this error when I reload the page with URL different from '/':

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactRouter.createServerRenderContext) is not a function
```

My server file is:

```
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import expressStaticGzip from 'express-static-gzip';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { ServerRouter, createServerRenderContext } from 'react-router';
import App from './app/components/App';

const app = express();

app.use('/', expressStaticGzip('dist'));

app.use((req, res) => {
  const context = createServerRenderContext();
  let markup = renderToString(
    <ServerRouter location={req.url} context={context} > <App /> </ServerRouter>);
  const result = context.getResult();

  if (result.redirect) {
    res.writeHead(301, {
      Location: result.redirect.pathname,
    });
    res.end();
  } else {
    if (result.missed) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      markup = renderToString(
        <ServerRouter location={req.url} context={context}> <App /> </ServerRouter>);
    }
    res.write(markup);
    res.end();
  }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.info(`Listening port ${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
});
```

My components are:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Main />
  </div>
);



const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/attendance" component={Attendance} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
);

const Header = () => (
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/attendance">Attendance</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
);
```

I am new with react-router 4 and I do not know how to solve this problem.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.